# Combining circuits for higer amperage

Tags: wiring, oven

I now have two single ovens - each on a 30 amp breaker with 10 gauge wiring. I want to replace the two single ovens with a double oven - which requires a 40 amp breaker.  Can I connect the two 10 gauge wires together into an 8 gauge pigtail to connect to a new 40 amp breaker?  There is plenty of room for another breaker.

Answer (score 1):

No - the breaker has to be sized for the conductor it protects.  Your 10 gauge conductors have to be treated as the separate conductors they are.  If one of the 10 gauge wires downstream was damaged, it could overheat without tripping the breaker.